# Can someone explain this odd Python/Django import behaviour?

Tags: python, django

I have a project where the directory structure looks like:

```
mywebsite/
    manage.py
    __init__.py
    myapp/
        models/
            __init__.py
            base.py
```

myapp/models/base.py contains:

```
class X(object):
    pass
```

myapp/models/__init__.py contains:

```
from base import X
```

Now, if I do manage.py shell I can have the following session:

```
> import mywebsite.myapp.models
> import myapp.models
> mywebsite.myapp.models.X == myapp.models.X
False
```

However if I change myapp/models/__init__.py to be:

```
from myapp.models.base import X
```

Then I get True as expected.

I think I am missing something about how imports work or how Django changes paths when using manage.py shell.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Daniel Roseman - you said this has nothing to do with Django. However, if I start a normal python session (whilst CDed into mywebsite) and do import mywebsite then I get an import error as expected. My suspicion is that Django is doing something that I don't understand with the path when I use manage.py shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a Django shell, it adds the path to your project to [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path). You can see this by running `import sys; print sys.path` on a Django shell and on a normal python shell and comparing the output. You will note that the output from the Django shell includes the path to the `mywebsite` directory as the first item of the list.

Basically, it means that the two imports create two different module objects, since they are gotten from [different points in the search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#tut-searchpath). The comparison check returns False since the module objects have different id's (memory address)

```
# These two values will be different
id(mywebsite.myapp.models)
id(myapp.models)
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense - I think I'd been staring (and shouting) at this for too long :D